# Owin JWT 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, owin, identityserver4

I'm trying to authenticate using IdentityServer4 and JWT.  I'm getting a token from my client and trying to post a simple request to one of my controllers.

I have a request like so

> GET api/Users
>
> Authorization: Bearer {{my-token}}

In my start up class I've registered

```
var authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
         .Build();

services.AddMvc(config => {
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicy)});

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.Authority = "https://localhost:44333";
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.ApiName = "MyApi";
    o.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = async context => {
            Console.WriteLine("Debugger");
        },
        OnMessageReceived = async context => {
            Console.WriteLine("Debugger");
        },

        OnTokenValidated = async tokenValidationContext =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Debugger");
        }
});
```

I've put break points at each one of the `Console.WriteLine("Debugger")` statements yet none of the break points hit.  Still I'm returned an unauthorized.

Is the header proper for my authorization?  I want to check the request when it fails, yet even with all exceptions turned on I cannot hit a break point, does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**
My Client Confiugration:

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("MyApi", "My Api"),
            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "customAPI",
                DisplayName = "Custom API",
                Description = "Custom API Access",
                UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"},
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("secretPassword".Sha256())},
                Scopes = new List<Scope>
                {
                    new Scope("customAPI.read"),
                    new Scope("customAPI.write")
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

The controller controller base:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AsyncCRUDSingleKeyServiceController<TDTO, TKey> : Controller
    where TKey : struct
{
    protected IAsyncCRUDService<TDTO> _service;

    public AsyncCRUDSingleKeyServiceController(IAsyncCRUDService<TDTO> service)
    {
        this._service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<TDTO> Get(TKey id)
    {
        return await this._service.Get(new object[] { id });
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Change https to http in this line: o.Authority = "http://localhost:44333";

Comment: A couple of things. Show your client configuration and your controller code. It sounds like you are hitting the API and not passing in a token for a user that has logged in. Have you looked at your token to see what claims and details are in the token. You can use https://jwt.io to see the details.

Comment: Https does not help either. I cannot even get a break point to hit before it returns 401

Comment: Did you include the line (before app.UseMvc) in Configure to use authentication: app.UseAuthentication();

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thank I was missing,  Now I'm able to hit break-points. If you add an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Startup.Configure, did you include the following line (before app.UseMvc)?

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```